# Extract parent domain/subdomain name from a list of url through Bash ShellScripting

Tags: bash, dns, extract

I have list of URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/sdfsdf/sdfsa
https://example2.com/53lasfd/asdfs
http://www.example3.com/asdfas/asdfasdf.php?=asdfa
https://subdomain.example4.com/index.php?id=sadfa
https://www.subdomain.example5.com/asdfas/asdfasd
```

I need to extract only domains (and subdomains) without `http`, `https`, `www` and all after `/`:

```
exmaple.com
exmaple2.com
example3.com
subdomain.example4.com
subdomain.example5.com
```

Comment: Sorry, output should be each at new line

Comment: I actually do not understand your question, because you said you want subdomain, but www is a subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`,

```
awk -F/ '{sub(/^www\.?/,"",$3); print $3}' yourfile
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk -F/ '{sub(/^www\.?/,"",$3); print $3}' yourfile
example.com
example2.com
example3.com
subdomain.example4.com
subdomain.example5.com
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: And what if I do not need subdomains but only domains?

Comment: Try : `awk -F/ '{sub(/^www\.?/,"",$3); print $3}' yourfile | awk -F\. 'NF==2'`

Comment: I definitely clicked UP, but it in someway gone -1, how can I edit this?